# We should be able to vote on our own community wiki posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, community-wiki

Since Community Wiki posts do not garner Rep for the poster, I suggest that we **should** be allowed to upvote (or downvote as the case may be) our **own** posts that are (or were made) Community Wiki.

Comment: If you think something is worth downvoting, why would you post it in the first place? Your name is attached to your posts, man!

Comment: @PopularDemand think about a poll for a feature on a meta site, where one could potentially post both options.

Comment: Maybe it was fine when you posted it, but then it gets edited to the point where you don't like it anymore?

Comment: @Toomai that you can just rollback...

Comment: I did think about that. First of all, polls are discouraged, even on meta sites. Second, if you must post a poll, you're not obligated to post an answer for the side you don't agree with. Wait for a supporter of that side to show up and do it for you.

Comment: By the time your post has become CW, you may not want to stand behind it any longer, and may feel it deserves down-voting...  (Not that I've ever actually seen this in practice, it just seems like a theoretical possibility).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I disagree.

The *main* purpose of voting is to separate good content from bad content.

The rep you can gain from those votes is just a side effect, so it shouldn't matter whether the post is Community Wiki or not.